# How do you get the pickups in Typing of the Dead Overkill?

Tags: the-typing-of-the-dead-overkill

When pickups appear on screen, how do I get them when in typing mode ?

It seems to have an icon on them (at least at the beginning) with two horizontal arrows in opposite directions, but I cannot figure out what key this is supposed to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Tab Key. That is the item pickup button in typing mode.

Comment: Ah my keyboard does not display this symbol for TAB. It would have been easier if they put <TAB> instead of this symbol for the people who have keyboards where it is written TAB. Thanks anyway.